# Does “syllabus” derive from Greek or Latin?

Tags: etymology, latin, origin-unknown, greek, irregular-plurals

I'm looking for some hard evidence to determine whether *syllabus* is a word that derives from Greek or Latin.

This came about from a discussion asking whether the plural of *syllabus* is *syllabuses* or *syllabi*. We deduced that the plural would be *syllabi* if it derived from Latin, but views conflicted as to whether the word actually derived from Latin, or if it actually has its roots in Greek.

Can anyone come up the answer to this conundrum?

Comment: I always figured it came from that funny little bus that clowns drive around in.

Comment: @HotLicks Σύλλαβοι

Comment: @tchrist - Ah, "that which holds together"!  Like a tiny bus stuffed with clowns!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=syllabus&searchmode=none) to the rescue:

> #### [syllabus (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=syllabus&searchmode=none)
>
> 1650s, “table of contents of a series of lectures, etc.,” from Late Latin *syllabus* “list,” ultimately a misreading of Greek *sittybos* “parchment label, table of contents,” of unknown origin. The misprint appeared in a 15c. edition of Cicero’s *Ad Atticum* ([see OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196148?redirectedFrom=syllabus#eid)). Had it been a real word, the proper plural would be *syllabi*.

The [full OED entry for the word](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196148) mentioned by Etymonline is much too long to fully cite here, but includes the following material pertinent to the current discussion:

> ## [syllabus (*n*.)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196148)
>
> ### Etymology
>
> < modern Latin *syllabus*, usually referred to an alleged Greek
>   *σύλλαβος*.  *Syllabus* appears to be founded on a corrupt reading *syllabos*
>   in some early printed editions — the Medicean MS. has *sillabos* — of
>   Cicero Epp.  ad Atticum ɪ. iv, where the reading indicated as correct by
>   comparison with the MS. readings in ɪ. v. and viii. is *sittybas* or Greek
>   *σιττύβας*, accusative plural of *sittyba*, *σιττύβα* parchment label or
>   title-slip on a book.  (Compare Tyrrell and Purser Correspondence of Cicero
>   nos. 107, 108, 112, Comm. and Adnot. Crit.) *Syllabos* was græcized by
>   later editors as *συλλάβους*, from which a spurious *σύλλαβος* was deduced
>   and treated as a derivative of *συλλαμβάνειν* to put together, collect
>   (compare [**ꜱʏʟʟᴀʙʟᴇ** *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196145)).
>
> In the passage from S. Augustine’s *Confessions* xɪɪɪ. xv. (‘ibi legunt
>   [sc. angeli] sine syllabis temporum quid velit aeterna voluntas tua’)
>   commonly adduced as further evidence of Latin syllabus, the word is clearly
>   *syllaba* syllable.

The earliest provided citation dates from a 1656 work by antiquary and
lexicographer Thomas Blount in his *Glossographia; or, A dictionary
interpreting all such hard words, whether Hebrew, Greek or Latin... as are
now used in our refined English tongue* (1ˢᵗ edition, 1656, London), where
he writes:

> - *Syllabus*, a Table or Index in a Book, to shew places or matter by
>     Letters or Figures.

This was quickly followed in 1667 by Jeremy Taylor, Church of Ireland
Bishop of Down and Connor, in the 4ᵗʰ edition of his work *The
great exemplar of sanctity and holy life* (1ˢᵗ edition 1649, 4ᵗʰ edition 1667), where he writes at ɪ. vi. §22. 160:

> - The Apostle expresses it still by Synonyma’s, *Tasting of the heavenly
>     gift, and made partakers of the holy Ghost*..; all which also are a
>     syllabus or collection of the several effects of the graces bestowed in
>     Baptism.

So, it seems that it is based on a misspelling of a Greek word — but that would hardly give one reason to form the plural in Greek starting from the Latin(ized) form.

According to both [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syllabus) and [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196148) alike, the plural can be either *syllabi*  /ˈsɪləbaɪ/ or *syllabuses*  /ˈsɪləbəsɪz/, but with Etymonline’s *“no real word”* verdict, I’d go for the latter.

Comment: Hey, it's a [Mumpsimus](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=Mumpsimus)! Didn't know that; thanks.

Comment: I came here only to mention that if there really *had been* a putative Greek *σύλλαβος* ‘syllabos’ in existence, that the putative 2ⁿᵈ declension plural would therefore have to have been *σύλλαβοι* ‘syllaboi’ — just so I could then make some cringeworthy **sillyboi** pun of that putatitious plural. But I ended up copyediting a tiny bit and adding supporting evidence using reference material from the OED;  hope you don’t mind.

Answer (score 1):

This word entered the Modern English vocabulary through late Middle English: from an Anglo-Norman French alteration of the Old French word sillabe, via Latin from Greek *sullabē* ('συλλαβή') a compound word coming from the preposition *'syn'* - meaning plus or together ('συν') + a form of the verb *'lambanein'* ('λαμβάνειν') to receive or take in Greek. The Greek preposition *'syn'* is a compound of many English words (synchronous, synthesis, synonym, synergy, syntax, syncope, synagogue) to denote actions that happen either concurrently or one is a consequence of the other. All of the above words, alongside many others, are of Greek origin and have travelled a long way through time and space from Southeastern Europe to the Northwest. Another interesting use of the preposition *'syn'* is in the word asynchronous meaning not existing or occurring at the same time, which also includes the prefix *'a-'* to express absence or negation.

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer, but unfortunately not to this question. You’re talking about the word **syllable** here, which is unrelated to _syllabus_.